# Maths Equation in Reports

Tags: java, javafx, ireport, crystal-reports-2010

How do I print a math equation written in JavaFX HTML editor? I wrote a math equation in Microsoft Word, then I copied and pasted it to the HTML editor. Now, I would like to print it, is there any other method?

Comment: I'm not sure, but some time I also tried to use HtmlEditor in fxml, and it didn't work as I needed.

Comment: did you use Pdf library for printing.

Comment: Try adding some code to your question so we can see exactly what you have, and explain what you want to do. If you just need to print something then look into pdfBox. I think you will find that the report libraries you use probably have a print function already, but we need to know what you are trying first, otherwise it is very hard to help.

Comment: What have you tried and what doesn't work? If you don't provide these details, this question is likely to be closed as "too broad" for the community.

Comment: I want to generate random exam paper from the save question in the database, Now, how to save the math equation in the database. and how to print it . Currently i am using jasper report.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which JavaFX version are you using ?

I suppose you pasted this equation as a picture ?

The next coming versions of JavaFX support MathML :

- JavaFX 8 Update 192 included in Java 8 Update 192
- JavaFX 11.

So if you want to display an equation, I suggest you use MathML.
And if you want to save it in a database, you simply have to copy the MathML code.

Follow this link Java [Early Access Download](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/ea-jsp-142245.html) to reach the early access to these versions.

I don't know Jasper Report but I understand that it uses xml file. Or XML, MathML, HTML, SVG belong to the same family language (SGML) : They are just strings. So you can wrap your HTML + MathML text and formula in an xml expression or may be replace the picture name you used before with these codes.
Then you can set WebView or HTMLEditor content using this HTML + MathML code.

Below, the MathML code to display the following quadratic formula.

[image: Quadratic formula]

```
<math display="block"> 
   <mrow> 
      <mi>x</mi> 
      <mo>=</mo> 
      <mfrac> 
         <mrow> 
            <mo>−</mo> 
            <mi>b </mi> 
            <mo>±</mo> 
            <msqrt> 
               <mrow> 
                  <msup> 
                     <mi>b</mi> 
                     <mn>2</mn> 
                  </msup> 
                  <mo>−</mo> 
                  <mn>4</mn> 
                  <mi>a</mi> 
                  <mi>c</mi> 
               </mrow> 
            </msqrt> 
         </mrow> 
         <mrow> 
            <mn>2</mn> 
            <mi>a</mi> 
         </mrow> 
      </mfrac> 
   </mrow>
</math>
```

Finally, print it :-) [How to Print with JavaFX](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/embedded-browser-tutorial/printing.htm).

Other documents in that tutorial also show you how to build the browser that implements all what you want.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Jasper report supports MathML? I am using Jasper report. How will i print it

Comment: You're welcome. I hope these additional informations could help you.

Comment: Thanks for valuable comments and answer. when i complete it,  I will let you know.